# remove special character from string in php

Tags: php, unicode

I have some text as below:

```
$cnt = "header text�
first line
�

The second line

�

other line
�"
```

can I remove all special text like `�` in my string?
i used `$cnt = str_replace("�", "", $cnt);`
but nothing change.

can you help me?

Comment: It seems a character encoding mess to me...maybe is produced when the values are stored in the database..you should use `utf8_encode($myval);` before you stored them...

Comment: It looks like line breaks that got broken. (Line breaks are commonly `\r\n` or `\n` character secuences.) Where do you get the string from?

Comment: Hi Robert, I tried with your suggestion, but string with Vietnamese will show like this "Bá»nh do Än uá»ng"

Comment: Hi Guffa, the string read from some pages

Comment: @NguyenBui: How do you read the string? Do you read it from file? Does it come from user input?

Comment: @Guffa: I use curl to get html content from web pages, then use Dom to get some elements.

Comment: @NguyenBui: Then there are several things that could be wrong, like character encoding and line break parsing. If you can find out the character codes of those `�` characters that might give a hint. A character shown as `�` can be any character that isn't covered by the font that you are using to view the text.

Answer (score 0):

What's your target character encoding? You may want to strip all non UTF-8 characters from your string. See here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4266468/1267408

Comment: I need to use UTF-8 for Vietnamese :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
$str = str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF",'',$str);
```

It removes utf-8 bom (byte-order mark) characters.

Comment: The BOM is only at the beginning of a file, not in the middle.

Comment: @Guffa Thanks for sharing .But above statement removes the special characters in from php string.